# How to get reference of parent Node in Apache myfaces tomahawk tree2 component

Tags: java, apache, jsf, myfaces, tomahawk

I have been doing rendering of directory structure in my jsf1.1 web page using Apache myfaces tomahawk tree2 component. In backing bean i have written a recursive function call to initialize folder names and documents names to be displayed in tree2 component.

Instance variables are:

```
private TreeNode treeData;
TreeNodeBase personNode=new TreeNodeBase();
TreeNodeBase folderNode;
```

In Method1:

```
personNode = new TreeNodeBase("folder",value from the database, false);
personNode.getChildren().add(new TreeNodeBase("document", document name, true));
```

If created folder has sub folders i call another method to find it's sub folders as well as it's documents. If exists adding the folders to parent folder with below code.

In Method2:

```
while(end of all folders list) {
folderNode = new TreeNodeBase("person", folder1, false);// add all folders
folderNode.getChildren().add(new TreeNodeBase("document", document name, true));//add document
personNode.getChildren().add(folderNode); //add sub folders to parent folder
}
```

Method which is binded to  component returns:

```
treeData.getChildren().add(personNode);
return treeData;
```

With this code i end up in adding all sub folders to single folder. So, i need to get parent folder reference(or ID) in order to add their child folders to it.

**My question is:** How to get the created folder id(or reference) with this line code or else suggest any other way of finding solution:

```
personNode = new TreeNodeBase("folder",value from the database, false);
```

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify each new **treenodebase()** to reference(or use) later we could use method **setIdentifier()** of TreeNodeBase class. By that we can identify each node uniquely.

```
folderNode.setIdentifier(folder identification number);// where folderNode is TreeNodeBase Object and folder identification number can be any unique number for created node.
```